# Video/Image Slider resize to fit screen (both width and height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this slider code to show my image and video:

`Code:`https://codepen.io/1wdtv/pen/jbjZeb

However the problem is that the slider is only responsive when it comes to the width. meaning if you resize your browser it will resize the image/video with it, without taking into regards its Height.

Is it possible to make the video/image fit exactly the screen from the height and width?

I want them to show on the screen witout having to scroll down in order to see the rest of the video/image.
even if it meant stretching the video/image

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
.slider-video {
  height: 100%;
}
video { 
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

This will make it take up the entire height. And it will stretch to fill the width. This may skew the video but you said that was acceptable.

Comment: Just be wary that this isn't [fully supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) across all browsers yet.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's supported on everything except Microsoft browsers (IE and Edge). Most people wanting responsive websites are more concerned about how the site will look on a phone or tablet and this will work fine on either.